# How to Decompress all .Z files with one command

Tags: python, debian

I'm using Debian. I have lot of files with ".z" format. I can only decompress all files with this command one by one:

```
python z_unpack.py "example.z" "example"
```

This command is running with this [script](https://github.com/TheCherry/ark-server-manager/blob/master/src/z_unpack.py)

I want to decompress all files in different directory with one command is it possible?

.Z files sample image in directory;

```
EXAMPLE/example1/example2.z
EXAMPLE/example1/example3.z
EXAMPLE/example2/example4.z
EXAMPLE/example3/example5.z
```

**NOTE:** This files are not GZIP they are not decompressed with gzip commands

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) :

```
import glob, os

def z_unpack_dir(dir):
    os.chdir(dir)
    for file in glob.glob("*.z"):
        file_name = os.path.basename(file)     # file_name = "example.z"
        dest_name = file_name[:-2]             # dest_name = "example"
        z_unpack(file_name, dest_name)
```

or os.listdir:

```
import os

def z_unpack_dir(dir):
    for file_name in os.listdir(dir):
        if file_name.endswith(".z"):
            dest_name = file_name[:-2]             # dest_name = "example"
            z_unpack(file_name, dest_name)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, sorry how should i use this ? Can you tell simply ?

Comment: I've updated the code to be a function called `z_unpack_dir`. Just call this function in main (`if __name__ == "__main__":`) with the directory name that you want.